# Arithmetic Overflow error -802

Tags: sql

Hi have a table that gets if data from a procedure, the procedure works fine but when trying to insert that data i get an arithmetic error and I'm not sure how you troubleshoot this. any help would be appreciated.

here is the procedure:

```
SET TERM ^ ;
CREATE PROCEDURE REPORT_CONTROLLEDGER (
  DATESTART Date,
  DATEEND Date,
  INCOMPANYID Integer )
RETURNS (
  GLCODE Varchar(8),
  DATUM Date,
  PERIOD Varchar(2),
  SOURCE Varchar(30),
  REFERENCENO Varchar(200),
  GLDESCRIPTION Varchar(200),
  DESCRIPTION Varchar(1000),
  DR Numeric(10,2),
  CR Numeric(10,2),
  COSTCODE Varchar(8),
  BALANCE Numeric(10,2),
  COMPANYID Integer )
AS
  declare lastglcode varchar (8);
  declare grouptype integer;
  declare tglcode varchar (8);
  declare tdatum date;
  declare tperiod varchar (2);
  declare tsource varchar (30);
  declare treferenceno varchar (200);
  declare tdescription varchar (1000);
  declare tdr numeric (10,2);
  declare tcr numeric (10,2);
  declare tcostcode varchar (8);


begin
  lastglcode = '';
  balance = 0;
  companyid = incompanyid;
  for select glcode, datum, period, source, referenceno, description, dr, cr, costcode from controlledger where companyid = :companyid and datum between :datestart and :dateend order by GLCODE, datum, id  
  into tglcode, tdatum, tperiod, tsource, treferenceno, tdescription, tdr, tcr, tcostcode  
do
begin
  select description from subcode where glcode = :tglcode and companyid = :companyid into :gldescription;
  if (lastglcode <> tglcode) then
  begin
    select grouptype from subcode where glcode = :tglcode and companyid = :companyid into :grouptype;

  if (grouptype = 1) then
  begin
    select sum (dr - cr) from CONTROLLEDGER where companyid = :companyid and glcode = :tglcode and datum < :datestart into :balance;  
    if (balance is null) then balance = 0;
    glcode = tglcode;
    referenceno = null;
    description = 'Balance Brought Forward';
    cr = null;
    dr = null;
    source = null;
    costcode = null;
    datum = null;
    period = null; -- added by Andre
    suspend;  

  end 
    else
  begin
    balance = 0;
  end 
  lastglcode = tglcode; 
end
glcode = tglcode;
referenceno = treferenceno;
description = tdescription;
cr = tcr;
dr = tdr;
source = tsource;
costcode = tcostcode;
datum = tdatum;
period = tperiod; -- added by Andre

balance = balance + (tdr - tcr);   
suspend;
end

end^
SET TERM ; ^

GRANT EXECUTE
 ON PROCEDURE REPORT_CONTROLLEDGER TO  SYSDBA;
```

here is the insert statement:

```
insert into tblreport_ledgercontrol select cast('03/01/2013' as date),
             cast('04/30/2014' as date),
             iif(cl.DATUM is null, 'now', cl.DATUM)as datum,
             'Detailed Ledger Report from 0000.000 to 9999.999 for period 01/03/2013 to 30/04/2014' as reporttitle,
               'ubuntu' as processedby,
                iif(cl.GLCODE is null, 00, cl.GLCODE)as glcode,
                iif(cl.PERIOD is null, 0 , cl.PERIOD)as period,
                iif(cl.SOURCE is null, 'n/a', cl.SOURCE)as source,
                iif(cl.REFERENCENO is null, 'n/a', cl.REFERENCENO)as referenceno,
                cl.GLDESCRIPTION,
                cl.DESCRIPTION,
                iif(cl.dr is null, 0, cl.dr)as dr,
                iif(cl.cr is null, 0, cl.cr)as cr,
                iif(cl.COSTCODE is null, 00, cl.COSTCODE)as costcode,
                cl.BALANCE,
                cl.COMPANYID,
                955,
                gen_id (GEN_TBLREPORT_LEDGERCONTROL_ID, 1)
        from report_controlledger ('03/01/2013','04/30/2014', 676) cl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your input, you were not far off from what was wrong. 
The procedure allowed for the description to be a varchar(1000) whilst the table it was inserting into allowed the description to be a varchar(200) and this caused the overflow error.

The soultion here was to change to desciption field in the destination table to a blob or to increase the char size of the description to match that of the procedure using an alter statement.

firebird sql:

```
alter table TBLREPORT_LEDGERCONTROL alter description type varchar(1000)
```

Comment: Okay. Does Firebird SQL say 'arithmetic overflow' when it is a truncation error?

Comment: it actually says both arithmetic overflow and string tuncation error. which makes it a little hard to figure out especially when you have numeric fields. my humble opinion

Answer (score 0):

I believe numeric overflow means you are trying to put 5 digits into a 4 digit field. (i.e.: cannot insert 12345 into a numeric (4,0) column)